sharing pdf to my ios react native app from gallery/files issue
Recently I implemented ShareExtension in my ios app built using react-native.
coming straight to the point.
added below code to info.plist of ShareExtension app to support sharing of any kind of file/attachments available
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
    <dict>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
    <integer>10</integer>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsMovieWithMaxCount</key>
    <integer>10</integer>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount</key>
    <integer>10</integer>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsAttachmentsWithMaxCount</key>
    <integer>10</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>

and now I

opened Photos

selected an image to share

from list of apps shown to share, I chose my app
from the below code I got the url details but could not repeat the same while sharing PDFs


NSExtensionItem *inputItem = self.extensionContext.inputItems.firstObject;
    NSItemProvider *itemProvider = inputItem.attachments.firstObject;

    if ([itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage options:nil completionHandler:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
            if (url) {
                NSLog(@"Shared file URL: %@", url);
                [self uploadFileWithURL:url];
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Error loading shared file: %@", error);
            }
        }];
    }

My trials - for sharing PDFs in the same manner,
if ([itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeFileURL]) {
      [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeFileURL options:nil completionHandler:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
          if (error) {
              NSLog(@"Error loading PDF: %@", error.localizedDescription);
            } else if (url) {
              NSLog(@"Shared PDF URL: %@", url);
            }
      }];
  }

just changed kUTTypeImage --> kUTTypeFileURL
but everytime its throwing error saying
Failed to resolve item of class `NSURL` for type `public.file-url` with error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=3 "No such process" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot issue a sandbox extension for file "/Users/demouser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{ID}/data/Containers/Data/Application/{SOME_ID}/Documents/PDF_NAME.pdf": No such process}

and also logging
Error loading PDF: Could not coerce an item to class NSURL
what I want ------> I just want to share the pdf file just like the image(which is working fine)
IF anybody have any prior experience, do kindly share, it will be very helpful.

is anybody alive on stack overflow ????????????????????????????????????????????
